# paypal order invoice

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, checkout, orders, paypal, onepage-checkout

I have a really weird phenomena happening w/ my checkout and paypal.

I'm using paypal express checkout; If I use any of the paypal express buttons to checkout,  when I return from paypal to finish the order and submit it - the quote is processed into an order and ***invoiced***. (**THIS IS THE FUNCTIONALITY I WANT**)

### Invoices orders when used this way

[image: Cart View]

When I use the normal One Page Checkout flow, and select paypal through that workflow, when I return from paypal to finish the order and submit it - the quote is processed into an order but **IS NOT** invoiced.

### Doesn't invoice orders this way

[image: one page checkout]

Anyone ever come across this? or ideas how to fix?  I have not modified the or overridden any functionality that deals w/ the payment gateways, and this is a pretty bare-bones site. Not a whole lot of extra functionality that would be messing anything up.

Comment: Did you find an answer here? Can you please update with your solution or mark the below answer as accepted?

Answer (score 2):

These are two differing methods - Express, and Standard.

It sounds like Standard is behaving the way you want, but Express is doing Authorize-Only. This is a system configuration option under `System > Configuration > Paypal > Express Checkout Settings`:

[image: paypal settings]

To capture payment and generate an invoice immediately, set it to 'Sale' or 'Order'. I'm honestly not sure of the difference between the two.

Comment: close, but that's backwards - express is working the way I want, standard is not.  I still like the idea you give, the only thing that's throwing me off is - all I have enabled is the 'paypal express checkout' section in admin.  I don't have standard enabled.  If I try to enable that as well, then I have to disable the express checkout.

Comment: Have you tried switching the payment action?